# Building composite through native .NET Core dependency injection

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core, ioc-container, composite

How can I create a composite implementation like the example bellow, but using native .NET Core DI container?

```
    [TestFixture]
    public class CompositeTests
    {
        [Test]
        public void BuildComposite()
        {
            var container = new UnityContainer();
            container.RegisterType<IFoo, SomeFoo>("first");
            container.RegisterType<IFoo, AnotherFoo>("second");
            container.RegisterType<IFoo, CompositeFoo>();

            var instanceOfFoo = container.Resolve<IFoo>();

            Assert.IsInstanceOf<CompositeFoo>(instanceOfFoo);
        }
    }

    public class CompositeFoo : IFoo
    {
        public CompositeFoo(IFoo[] others)
        {
            Debug.Assert(others != null);
            Debug.Assert(others.Any());
        }
    }

    public class AnotherFoo : IFoo {}
    public class SomeFoo : IFoo {}
    public interface IFoo {}
```

> Composite in this case “consumes” an array of child objects and in a
>   sense “sucks in” every implementation of IFoo registered with a key.
>   This is an important aspect: if you were to register composite with a
>   key, it would try to instantiate itself leading in immediately to
>   StackOverflowException.

The native DI doesn't support these named registrations.

This example is extracted from [here](http://sharpfellows.com/post/Unity-IoC-Container-)

Answer (score 5):

In [our book](https://mng.bz/BYNl), [Mark](https://blog.ploeh.dk/) and I describe how to register non-generic composites for Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (section 15.4.4).

```
services.AddTransient<SomeFoo>();
services.AddTransient<AnotherFoo>();

services.AddTransient<IFoo>(c =>
    new CompositeFoo(
        new IFoo[]
        {
            c.GetRequiredService<SomeFoo>(),
            c.GetRequiredService<AnotherFoo>(),
        }));
```

As this example shows, registration is reasonably simple, but as we describe in our book, from here on it gets very complicated really quickly. For instance, Auto-Wiring is out of the picture, and when you start mixing this with Auto-Registration or when you have a generic abstraction, things get way more complicated.